# Feeds and pipe | separated values

Tags: feeds

I am trying to use Feeds to import data from a CSV file. However, the file I've been provided with, even though its type is "Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv)", the values are separated by a pipe | character instead!

Will this work? Or will it corrupt the database?

The reason I ask this is because in the Select a parser section one of the options is CSV parser (parse data in comma separated value format) and that is the only one that I can see would suit me... except for my pipe separated values format ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work out of the box because Feeds is expecting a CSV but you can convert this to a proper CSV file using the [Feeds Tamper module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) to modify the data before passing it to feeds.

However, the easier way to do this would be to just load the file back into Microsoft Excel as a delimited file, and then export it back as a proper CSV.

Comment: Thanks for that. I saved the excel file as a CSV, but uploading it did not import any items. (Status No imported items.)

What I did was replace the original header row with the one that the drupal generated template produced. I made sure that the columns matched up and reflected the field/mapping structure/order.

Any tips?

Comment: That could be any number of issues - are you making sure to export the data as UTF-8? When you open up the CSV file in a text editor does it look normal? What are you using for line breaks? Check the description under CSV on this page for some more tips on how to make sure your file is in the correct format for imports: http://drupal.org/node/622710#csv